# Application verifier and OpenGL calls

Tags: opengl, windbg, nvidia, application-verifier

I am using **Application Verifier** to  test app.without Application verifier app runs normally.
but with Application Verifier when application reaches at   `nvoglv64!DrvPresentBuffers+0x1e1d8e` throw exception(access violation). after that ,I used  Application Verifier with a very simple OpenGl sample it also throw the same exception at the same place.my driver is nvidia 320.49.is it a driver issue ?

Comment: Yes, Application Verifier is a quality gate for application. The problem with module nvoglv64 has to be root caused and fixed. It might have been fixed in latest driver. Try with latest driver.

Comment: It is the latest driver :320.49. My graphic card is: GTX 660 ti,

Comment: is there any way to exclude a module from verifying by Application verifier?

Comment: With Application Verifier, I guess we can't exclude a particular module. Btw, why would you want to do that? If you suspect the issue with driver, then report the issue to Nvidia they will look into it.

Comment: I unchecked TLS and Theadpol from basics it passed with simple opengl application.but with  my application it still break on a function at nvogl64.dll .